# How to set multiple registries in .npmrc for different repositories with auth

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-registry, .npmrc

I am currently working on a project and I have to install the dependencies from multiple registries.

1. Public repositories from the default npm registry
2. My own private repositories (scoped) from npm registry using `_authToken`
3. From nexus repository (without scope) from nexus registry using `_auth`

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.